# load page in div via javascript

Tags: javascript, image, load, var

Am Sure this question has been asked many times, but i need to do the following

```
<script language="javascript">
var one = 888;
var two = 122;
var three = "ABC";
</script>
```

I need to send those and return the data in a DIV (it will be an image)

I dont wont to use jQUERY or any other plugin

http://www.example.com/yes?one=888&two=122&three=ABC

Comment: Why not use jquery? JQuery is no plugin, it's a javascript library. It's the same as when you write all the code and simplifies it. You need to send it? With Ajax?

Comment: You can use AJAX if the content located on the same domain. If it's not, you'll need to connect to the resource using sockets, which probably implies the need to implement a server-side solution, as WebSockets aren't widely supported yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do. This will set the src of an image to what you asked for and add it to the div.

```
img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://www.example.com/yes?one=' + one + '&two=' + two + '&three=' + three;
document.querySelectorAll('#idOfDiv').appendChild(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery make it simple, but if you want you can do it in pure JS. Read official w3c ajax tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp